# How to locate another object in a JFrame?

Tags: java, jframe, abstract

Let's suppose that there is another object in a specific JFrame that uses the same abstract class.

Now I'm wondering how to find the location of an object inside the JFrame as it's moving automatically.

I have a superclass that's a board.

Inside that board, I have a bunch of objects that all share the same abstract class but are coded differently.

I want to use those objects to locate each other without editing the field class.

How would I do that?

Comment: I assume you mean they are components of some kind?  Otherwise, you will need devise some kind of model through which you can gain access to the objects

Answer (score 0):

Store those objects in a `List<AbstractClassName>` and you can iterate over them every time you want to perform some action on all of them, or search some specific one based on it's properties if you want only one of them.